# Repeating dependent parsers with Scala/SBT parser combinators

Tags: scala, sbt

Parsing a string of the form `Value[,Value]+` can be easily accomplished via `rep1sep(Value, ',')`.  Is there a way to achieve rep1sep functionality when the Value parser is dependent on the previously parsed Values in the repetition?  For example, enforcing a requirement that each value must be unique?

The standard technique for dependent parsers is flatMap, but I am having trouble getting that working.  Here's one such attempt:

```
def Values(soFar: Set[Value]): Parser[Set[Value]] =
  Value(soFar) flatMap { v => (',' ~> Values(soFar + v)).?.map { _ getOrElse soFar } }

def Value(soFar: Set[Value]): Parser[Value] =
  Num+ flatMap { v => if (soFar.contains(v)) failure("%d already appears".format(v)) else success(v) }
```

Generically, I need a form of rep1sep where the parser argument is a function from `Seq[A]` to `Parser[A]`:

```
def rep1sepDependent(rep: Seq[A] => Parser[A], sep: Parser[Any]): Seq[A] = ???
```

Note: I realize the use case is questionable here and that validating uniqueness is better handled post parsing.  I've encountered this problem while using the SBT parsing combinators for the purpose of tab completion -- specifically, I'd like to present completion options for key/value pairs for only those keys that the user has not already entered.  See [this parser for a full example](https://github.com/mpilquist/cjmx/blob/c450e96463ae9b55308db545ab1bbba1c7f10b0b/src/main/scala/cjmx/cli/ObjectNameParser.scala#L30) and buildable SBT project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following isn't quite as generic as your `rep1sepDependent`, but it works:

```
def rep1sepUnique[T](p: => Parser[T], q: => Parser[Any]) = {
  def checkIfSeen(seen: Set[T]): Parser[Set[T]] = q ~> p >> (v =>
    if (seen(v)) failure("Duplicate: %s".format(v)) else checkIfSeen(seen + v)
  ) | success(seen)
  p >> (v => checkIfSeen(Set(v)))
}
```

For example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object parseUniqueWords extends RegexParsers {
  def rep1sepUnique[T](p: => Parser[T], q: => Parser[Any]) = {
    def checkIfSeen(seen: Set[T]): Parser[Set[T]] = q ~> p >> (v =>
      if (seen(v)) failure("Duplicate: %s".format(v)) else checkIfSeen(seen + v)
    ) | success(seen)
    p >> (v => checkIfSeen(Set(v)))
  }

  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(rep1sepUnique("\\w+".r, ","), s)
}
```

Which gives us:

```
scala> parseUniqueWords("aaa,bb,c")
res0: parseUniqueWords.ParseResult[Set[String]] = [1.9] parsed: Set(aaa, bb, c)

scala> parseUniqueWords("aaa,bb,aaa")
res1: parseUniqueWords.ParseResult[Set[String]] = 
[1.11] failure: Duplicate: aaa

aaa,bb,aaa
          ^
```

Which is what we want.

Comment: Thanks! I generalized to rep1sepDep but I'm left with the same tab completion problem my current implementation has.  I'm now wondering if this is a quirk in the SBT completion support when using flatMap.

Comment: Scratch that - bug was due to an overly accepting production in an earlier part of the parser.  For details: https://github.com/mpilquist/cjmx/commit/6f146c8c74fd45252e1fba6b665a4f9909565f79

Comment: Are `scala.util.parsing` and SBT parsers compatible?

Comment: I answer myself: no, they are similar but not identical.  `scala.util.parsing` doesn't support autocompletion.

Comment: What is the `>>` operator in `p >> (v => ....)`?.   `RichParser` doesn't contain this method in SBT 0.13.9.

Comment: @david.perez It's just an alias for `flatMap` (and [an ill-advised one, in my opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21261067/334519)).

Comment: Please, can an example be provided for SBT parsers with completion?  The given example is for Scala parsers.  If necessary a can create a separate Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Already written a working implementation!.  It's not so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for selecting some items with assisted completion, avoiding duplicated items:

```
def select1(items: Iterable[String], separator: Parser[_] = Space) =
  token(separator ~> StringBasic.examples(FixedSetExamples(items)))

def selectSome(items: Seq[String], separator: Parser[_] = Space): Parser[Seq[String]] = {
   select1(items, separator).flatMap { v ⇒
   val remaining = items filter { _ != v }
   if (remaining.size == 0)
     success(v :: Nil)
   else
     selectSome(remaining).?.map(v +: _.getOrElse(Seq()))
 }
```

}

Example of use:

```
val myTask = inputTask[Unit]("Print selected numbers")
myTask := {
  val numbers = selectSome(Seq("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")).parsed
  numbers.foreach{ println _ }
}
```

Tested with SBT 0.13.9.