# When to use scala triple caret (^^^) vs double caret (^^) and the into method (>>)

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Can someone explain how and when to use the triple caret ^^^ (vs the double caret ^^) when designing  scala parser combinators?  And also when / how to use the parser.into() method (>>).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll begin with an example using Scala's `Option` type, which is similar in some important ways to `Parser`, but can be easier to reason about. Suppose we have the following two values:

```
val fullBox: Option[String] = Some("13")
val emptyBox: Option[String] = None
```

`Option` is monadic, which means (in part) that we can `map` a function over its contents:

```
scala> fullBox.map(_.length)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> emptyBox.map(_.length)
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

It's not uncommon to care only about whether the `Option` is full or not, in which case we can use `map` with a function that ignores its argument:

```
scala> fullBox.map(_ => "Has a value!")
res2: Option[String] = Some(Has a value!)

scala> emptyBox.map(_ => "Has a value!")
res3: Option[String] = None
```

The fact that `Option` is monadic also means that we can apply to an `Option[A]` a function that takes an `A` and returns an `Option[B]` and get an `Option[B]`. For this example I'll use a function that attempts to parse a string into an integer:

```
def parseIntString(s: String): Option[Int] = try Some(s.toInt) catch {
  case _: Throwable => None
}
```

Now we can write the following:

```
scala> fullBox.flatMap(parseIntString)
res4: Option[Int] = Some(13)

scala> emptyBox.flatMap(parseIntString)
res5: Option[Int] = None

scala> Some("not an integer").flatMap(parseIntString)
res6: Option[Int] = None
```

This is all relevant to your question because `Parser` is also monadic, and it has `map` and `flatMap` methods that work in very similar ways to the ones on `Option`. It also has a bunch of confusing operators (which [I've ranted about before](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/379600827930787840)), including the ones you mention, and these operators are just aliases for `map` and `flatMap`:

```
(parser ^^ transformation) == parser.map(transformation)
(parser ^^^ replacement) == parser.map(_ => replacement)
(parser >> nextStep) == parser.flatMap(nextStep)
```

So for example you could write the following:

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  def parseIntString(s: String) = try success(s.toInt) catch {
    case t: Throwable => err(t.getMessage)
  }

  val digits: Parser[String] = """\d+""".r
  val numberOfDigits: Parser[Int] = digits ^^ (_.length)
  val ifDigitsMessage: Parser[String] = digits ^^^ "Has a value!"
  val integer: Parser[Int] = digits >> parseIntString
}
```

Where each parser behaves in a way that's equivalent to one of the `Option` examples above.

Comment: Perfect!  Short, succinct, pragmatic and to the point answer!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Again, thanks for this concise answer! Although I'm aware that one of Scala's strengths is its conciseness, at least compared to Java, is it fully necessary to use these carets when writing Parsers, or can the developer write 'long-hand' map references (I favour this in my own code, simply for readability)? I assume that the compiler will optimise and generate equivalent code, right?