# what does ^^ mean in sparsing a string?

Tags: scala, playframework

A parser that tries to parse a String into an Object which uses a "^^". For example, following parser is parsing a line of `message.en` in playframework into a Message object:

```
val message = ignoreWhiteSpace ~ messageKey ~ (ignoreWhiteSpace ~ "=" ~ ignoreWhiteSpace) ~ messagePattern ^^ {
    case (_ ~ k ~ _ ~ v) => Message(k, v.trim)
  }
```

What does `^^` mean in the above code?

Comment: "sparsing" a string means to remove a majority of the characters and leave blank spaces in their stead.

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21261067/334519).

Comment: Hi Travis, that is a correct answer too. However I didn't realise that it has been answered anywhere because the operator "^^" is kind of special keyword, and it does not return any useful results from both Google or Stackoverflow. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a method defined on a `scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers.Parser` type. It's signature is `def ^^[U](f: T => U): Parser[U]` (defined on an instance of `Parser[T]`).

If we have a parser `p` of type `Parser[T]` and a function `f` of type `T => U`, then doing `p ^^ f` means "run parser p, if we can successfully parse with p, then convert the parsed result to a type U using f." If parsing with `p` fails, then we never invoke `f`.

[Specific answer]
So... in the above code, if the parser `ignoreWhiteSpace ~ messageKey ~ (ignoreWhiteSpace ~ "=" ~ ignoreWhiteSpace) ~ messagePattern` succeeds, then we'll turn the result into a `Message` type! `{ case (_ ~ k ~ _ ~ v) => Message(k, v.trim) }` is a function here (our `f` if you will).

Hope this clears it up!

PS - Here's the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser).