# Parser with dependent tokens

Tags: parsing, sbt

Building parsers for `inputTask`s are powerful and incredibly easy to use.

But now I have a use case, I don't know to express:

I would like to create a parser like this:

```
token(Space ~> language) ~ token(Space ~> number).+
```

where `language` can be one of theses 3 values:

- English
- French
- Spanish

and `number` can be one of theses 3 values:

- one, two, three for English
- un, deux, trois for French
- uno, dos, tres for Spanish.

Our parser can be easily written as:

```
token(Space ~> StringBasic.examples(FixedSetExamples("English", "French", "Spanish")) ~ 
token(Space ~> number).+
```

but I don't know how to write `number`, because it is dependent of the value of `language`.

Example inputs:

- English one one
- Spanish dos
- French trois deux

I think this must be possible, because i.e. the arguments of a command or an input task, depend on the command type.  I've studied the source code of SBT, but it is hard to understand.

More info:

- [Related documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Parsing-Input.html).
- [Repeating dependent parsers with Scala/SBT parser combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303997/repeating-dependent-parsers-with-scala-sbt-parser-combinators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flatMap and create a second parser that is based on the first one:

```
val languageNumbersParser = {
    import complete.DefaultParsers._
    val languages: Parser[String] = literal("English") | "French" | "Spanish"
    val engNums: Parser[String] = literal("one") | "two" | "three"
    val freNums: Parser[String] = literal("un") | "deux" | "trois"
    val spaNums: Parser[String] = literal("uno") | "dos" | "tres"
    token(Space ~> languages) flatMap {
      case "English" => success("English") ~ token(Space ~> engNums).+
      case "French" => success("French") ~ token(Space ~> freNums).+
      case "Spanish" => success("Spanish") ~ token(Space ~> spaNums).+
    }
}
```

Comment: It works.  It is an undocumented feature of SBT parsers.  Without your help it is very hard to know this.